# Git seems to change branches by itself

Tags: git

I have two git branches, `master` and `other`, and when working on `other`, git seemingly spontaneously changes the current branch to `master`. It also brings all the uncommitted changes with it, so that `git diff` lists every difference between my current working files and the most recent commit on `master`. This is a real pain to sort out, because of course git won't let me checkout back to `other` with uncommitted changes!

To be clear, no git commands are entered at all - the change happens two consecutive `git status` calls.

Any idea what might be causing this or what I can do to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using more than one window for git commands? Or some GUI or an IDE perhaps?

Comment: No, only one terminal window open, and as I said no git commands are executed in it when the change seems to happen. I am using eclipse to edit the files, but it is unaware of git, and I haven't used it for version control at all, only the terminal.

Comment: Plus I'm not aware of any git command that could cause this to happen, else I could just use it to change back to other!

Comment: can you document this with a printout from git reflog before and after the ghost attacks?

Comment: The most likely culprit is something, such as a cron job or `ssh` run elsewhere, that does a `git checkout` while you're working on the repository.  For instance, if you're working on the git repo of a deployed site and some "deploy" script in a hook does `cd where-you-are && git checkout -f`.

Comment: Thanks both! I wasn't aware of the reflog tool, which was helpful in finding the culprit - it was indeed a (gitolite) git hook, that I hadn't realised runs as part of our integration tests.